# Setting up a ssh key connection for git between Windows and Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssh, git

I am trying to set up a workflow where I do not need to enter the password for my server account every time I want to `push` to it.

I am setting up a deploying system where the server is a Ubuntu machine, and my development station runs Windows. I've created a `bare` repository and `clone`'d it to my Windoes machine. Every time I `push` to it I am asked for the password for `user@server` . I've added my Windows `id_rsa.pub` to the `known_hosts` on the server but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

> I've added my Windows `id_rsa.pub` to the `known_hosts` on the server but to no avail.

You need to add your `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`!

Comment: I tried but I still get asked for a password. I checked the config file in `.ssh/`  though and it is empty. Is it possible that that `authorized_keys` file is not even read at all, as I had to create it.

Comment: you should check the permissions on that file on server. `~/.ssh` should be `700` and `authorized_keys` should be `600`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Jakuje, but it is still asking for a password.

Comment: And what errors you see in server log?

Comment: I removed the edit, because i managed to get it working. I transfered the public key via winscp and used cat >> to copy it and it worked. I guess copying with copy and paste added lines and screwed it up. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

To properly use SSH-Technology on Windows, I recommend using [putty](http://www.putty.org/). It does take care of all the hassle using SSH-Technology on Windows. Once installed, launch Pageant (PuTTY SSH-Agent) and load your private key. Pushing should work now.

Comment: I do actually use PuTTY for working on the server, but never thought I could use it like that. Great piece of software ! Thank you !